# Child Interface pointing Parent Interface implementing class

Tags: java, class, interface

I'm checking one code with below exact same logic but not able to understand how its happening. So please bear with me..! :)

```
class A implements I{}

class B extends A{}

class C extends B{}

interface I{}

interface I2 extends I{}

interface I3 extends I2{}

class Top{

    public static void main(String[] args){

      I3 ob = new A();   //Step I
    }
}
```

Its not possible at Step 1, but I'm reviewing one code where this kind of logic is happening without any error. May I know please if this is happening without error than what else could be looked to check its happening right ? What are the possibilities when Step 1 is right ?

Thanks

Comment: Java keywords are `class` and `interface`. Not `Class` and `Interface`.

Comment: You cannot start an identifier (interface name, class name etc.) with a number in Java. So `interface 1 {}` does not compile.

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda, thanks for editing. Any idea on my question ?

Comment: `A` is not an `I3` object  so  `I3 ob = new A();` is an error

Comment: @c0der, Yes Ideally it should be error. But its not. Any other possibility is there where it can work ?

Comment: It does not even compile. Post [mcve] that does it without an error.

Comment: @Andrea, actually c0der has edited the question. So, the credit should go to c0der :)

Answer (score 1):

Class A will have only the implementations of Interface `I` 
A variable has two types: a declared (or static) type and a run time type.

`I3 ob = new A();`

So, This `ob` variable is declared as type `I3` and the object it references is of type A. This will give you compile time exception. And ask you to cast to `I3`.
But still you will get run time exception 'java.lang.ClassCastException'.

**You can assign a reference to a variable of its super type only**. Interface `I` is the super type of Class `A`. Interface `I3` is not the super type of Class A.

If you had,

```
 class A implements I3{}
```

then it `A` would have had all the implementation of `I`, `I2` and `I3`. Then, 
  `I3 ob = new A();` 
 would have been possible.

Possibilities when Class `A` implements `I3`:

You can use `ob` to call the methods of Interface `I`,`I2` and `I3`. You can check if implementation in Class `A` is returned.

Comment: `Class A will have all the implementations of Interface 1, 2 and 3` I can't see that in the code posted. `A` only implements `I`  (or 1)

Comment: Andrea, had posted a code which had Interfaces named 1, 2 and 3. Now he has changed the code. My answer was to the code which he had posted earlier. @Andrea please create a new thread if you want to change the question.

Comment: The question was not changed. Only the names changed to valid java names.

Comment: Not just the names, before Class A was implementing I3. Now you have changed it to implement I

Comment: Class A was implementing 1.

Comment: "Interface A,B and C"  do you mean I , I2, I3 ?

Answer (score 1):

See my elaboration in below code comments.

```
class A implements I{}

class B extends A{}

class C extends B{}

interface I{}

interface I2 extends I{}

interface I3 extends I2{}

class Top {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    I ob1 = new A(); // Compiles bcoz A "is an" I
    I2 ob2 = new A(); // Does not compile bcoz A "is not an" I2
    I3 ob3 = new A(); // Does not compile bcoz A "is not an" I3
  }                  
}
```

Comment: So I assume your answer implies that the question to  "What are the possibilities when Step 1 is right" is none.

Comment: @But what if A implements I3, then I ob3 = new A(); will work ..! It think its like parent child relation. Child cannot swallow parent but parent can do ..! :)

Comment: " what if A implements I3, then I ob3 = new A(); will work"  show us a case that it does.

Comment: @c0der, It will compile ..I'm sure..! :)

Comment: @c0der, But am still not able to get my answer nowhere ..! :(

Comment: "But am still not able to get my answer nowhere" you got 2 good answers here. I am sorry that these are not the answers you want.  "I'm sure" does not prove anything but that.

Comment: @Andrea, in the questions you said _"I'm reviewing one code where this kind of logic is happening without any error"_. May be you can post that code to understand what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's up-casting in java. for example, when you define class C as extended of B and B as extended of A, then, you can use container A as a holder for object of C:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B
```

then you can define an object of C like below:

```
A a = new C();
```

A good example in java is defining ArrayList:

```
List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

you know that ArrayList definition is:

```
class ArrayList implements List { ... }
```

Comment: `C c = new A();` does not compile

Comment: `A a = new C();` is correct, because `C` is also an `A` ( while `A` is not necessarily a `C`) , but I do not see how it answers the question.